# How can I verify an APK file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, apk

I'm creating a page in my web app where the user can upload an apk file. Before I send it to the server, is there a way I can verify the apk file (using signature)? Or read the signature using JavaScript?
My app is made in React.js.

The element is equivalent to:

`<input type='file' accept=".apk">`

Comment: "Very an APK file" - What do you exactly mean? Verifying the file type?

Comment: I want to verify that the apk is valid; i.e.; it is not a debug release or malicious.
Similar to what is achieved here: https://apkpure.com/apk-signature-verification